# create one row from two columns sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to create one row from two columns?

Example:

```
id    description
------------------
1      one
2      two
3      three
```

In result:

```
1: one, 2: two, 3: three
```

I use follow statment:

```
select Id,
  stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + cast(Description as varchar(10))
           FROM dbo.tbl t2
           where t2.Id = t1.Id
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from dbo.tbl t1
group by Id
```

But in result I have two columns. I need one such as string

Comment: It's called PIVOT.

Comment: do you need to be in 3 column too or you want to concatenate as string

Comment: @MahdyAslamy I need string

Comment: What's your sql-server version?

Comment: @D-Shih 2008 version

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query.

```
CREATE TABLE T (
   id int,
   description varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO T  VALUES (1,'one');
INSERT INTO T  VALUES (2,'two');
INSERT INTO T  VALUES (3,'three');
```

**Query 1**:

```
select 
      stuff((SELECT ', ' + CAST(t2.ID AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':'+ t2.description 
               FROM t t2
               FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a215e/11/0)**:

```
|                        |
|------------------------|
|  1:one, 2:two, 3:three |
```

Comment: The concat function was introduced in 2012 version. do u think it will work in 2008 as he is mentioned in the comment.

Comment: @Ramji Yeah( It;s no work in 2008 version. I have error: 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: instead of concat use '+' symbol ,  t2.id + ':' +  t2.description

Comment: @KirillRodeonov Use `+` instead of `CONCAT` function

Comment: @D-Shih Thank you. It helps

Comment: @KirillRodeonov No Problem glad to help

Answer (score 2):

i think you are asking for this

```
select stuff((SELECT ', ' + CAST(tbl.id AS varchar) + ':' + tbl.description
FROM tablename tbl FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')  as Columnname
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close..

```
declare   @T TABLE  (
  id int,
   description varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO @T  VALUES (1,'one');
INSERT INTO @T  VALUES (2,'two');
INSERT INTO @T  VALUES (3,'three');

select Id,
  stuff((SELECT distinct ', ' + +cast(id as nvarchar) +':'+description
           FROM @T t2
           where t2.Id = t1.Id
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') 
from @T t1
group by Id
```

OR If you want all the ids in a sing row use the below query

```
select stuff((select ',' +cast(id as nvarchar) +':'+description  
from @T for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

select statement is like a for loop or an iterator and you you need a space to save you data and it's not possible with select only because in the moment select statement only access to a row not previous row and not next row so

please use a scaler-value function

```
create function test()
return
    nvarchar(max)
as
begin

    declare @s nvarchar(max)

    select @s = concate(@s, id, description)
    from yourTable

    return @s
end
```

Comment: you can use functions like tables and views - and probably you need to cast id to nvarchar